# How to connect Crystal Report and MySQL in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, crystal-reports

To clarify things first, I can connect MySQL to VB.NET. But I can't connect Crystal Report and MySQL. When I'm creating new report in CrystalReportViewer control, I am stucked at the Standard Report Creation Wizard window. I can't see any connections and my database (I created it in MySQL Query Browser).

I'm using: Visual Studio 2010[image], MySQL Query Browser, SQL Server 2005, Crystal Report(CRforVS13_0_13)

Any help? Or am I just missing something?

Comment: If you open up ODBC data sources, can you see MySQL under Drivers ?

Comment: Only Excel Files and MS Access Database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crystal Report requires an ODBC driver.  You can find one [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/).

After you have installed it, check that it exists in the ODBC Data Sources.

[image: It must be visible here. When I get home, I can instal it and show you hat the text looks like.]

Once there, you need to create an Alias.  Click on the **User DSN** tab and press the <kbd>Add</kbd> button.  Test the connection then go to Crystal reports.

Comment: How should I do that?

Comment: Okay I'll come back after I install it

Comment: Done installing, what should I do next? I checked it and nothing changes

Comment: Test Failed? I selected Sql Server and choose (local) for the server

Comment: @LeeSong, SQL Server is Microsofts SQL server.  You need to select Mysql.  I cant tell you what it looks like for another an hour.

Comment: There is 2 MySQL, MySQL ODBC 5.3 Ansi Driver and MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver, which should I select?